# Scheduling JMS listener in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I have a method in a Spring Boot application that listens to a queue in ActiveMQ. I want to schedule the method so that it does not start listening to the queue on application startup and runs every X minutes.

Here is the method that I wrote to accomplish the task. I have disabled the `JMSListener` auto startup so that it does not start listening on when the application is started.

```java
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000, initialDelay = 1000)
@JmsListener(destination = "queueName")
public void receiveMessage(final Message jsonMessage) throws JMSException {
   System.out.println("Received message " + jsonMessage);

}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
   DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
   factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
   factory.setConcurrency("1-1");
   factory.setAutoStartup(false);
   return factory;
}
```

But when I run the application I get an exception which says that the scheduled method cannot have arguments:

```
Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'receiveMessage': Only no-arg methods may be annotated with @Scheduled
```

Is there a way I can schedule the `JMSListener` so that it starts after a delay on the application startup and is scheduled to run every X minutes and read messages from the queue?

Comment: I don't think annotation `@Scheduled` and `@JmsListener` are compatible. Why do you need such behaviour?

Comment: You should ask yourself : "Why using a listener if you don't whant to listen ?" And may be think about an other solutuion, like listening 100% of time, stackibng the massage into your application, AND processing the message at the moment you whant to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `@Scheduled` there.

Use the `JmsListenerEndpointRegistry` bean to start and stop the listener when needed.

```
@JmsListener(id = "foo" ...)


registry.getListenerContainer("foo").start();
...
registry.getListenerContainer("foo").stop();
```